# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28+

Tags: android

I am new to Android Studio. I am now using Android Studio 2.2.1 due to my study. I found the relevant answer on the website, I tried all solution but I still doesn't work.

```
android {

compileSdkVersion 28

buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.quynhnhu.demoapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.+'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
```

Comment: Change with "...v7:28.0.0"

Comment: Please update Android Studio first and then try this again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the google maven repository for `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.+` in your **project**/**root** build.gradle. So, change your build.gradle to include the repository like the following:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {

        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
}
```

more details at [Support Library Setup](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup).

Note: please update your gradle version and Android Studio.

Comment: So it means I need to update the Android Studio to the newest version ?

Comment: You better to update your Android Studio. But if your project is in deadline, make a copy of your all Android Studio then gradually update your project with the newest Android Studio just to keep a working state. Don't forget to use git.